# Can we ask a question ourselves and then answer ourselves if we have some research work?

Tags: support

If I have a research work on any topic which is valuable to others too and I don't find any related question on Stack Overflow, can I post a question myself then answer it myself so that other users can be benefited ?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Please make sure it's a good valid question on it's own. Self-answering is encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as:

1. It's decent, and well written
2. It's most certainly not a dupe (search extensively)
3. It is not too localised to a specific issue or code that would only
   help a few other users with *similar code*

Info:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

[Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)